# What does the blue radius mean?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

In GTA5, a blue radius will appear on the mini-map.

I've noticed it appear when I enter some buildings, but I can't figure out what the connection is.

What does it mean?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Blue radius is the noise of your footsteps, your character's voice, or weapons. It shows the radius of the sound travel. If a character that can detect you is in that radius you will be caught.

Answer (score 4):

The blue radius also seems to appear when you are out in the open doing something naughty. For example, assaulting a passer-by or breaking into a car.

I thought it to be an indicator that passing cops might take more notice of you.